# daily push notifications at the same time for 10 days

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS, is there an easy way to send a push notification for 10 days at the same time each day? I do not wish to send the push notifications to ALL users. The way that my app works, a user gets to choose one time for push notifications for ten consecutive days. Are there any APIs you would recommend for this? Or is there a way to do with with local push notifications (in Swift)?

Thanks!

Comment: Swift is the same as objective c. and yes it's just scheduled local notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**In Appdelegate**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.requestAuthorization([.alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
         if granted{ 
             // do you work
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

**General Function**

```
func scheduleMyNotificationWith(date: Date, body: String) {     
    let triggerWeekly = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,hour,.minute,.second,], from: date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerWeekly, repeats: true)

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "your notification title" // it is mendatory
    content.body = body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    //content.categoryIdentifier = "todoList"

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "textNotification", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self
    //UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) {(error) in
      if let error = error {
        print("Somethings went to wrong: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }
```